# convert nodejs function to AWS Lambda compatible

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am pretty new to both nodejs and AWS Lambda. I have created a very small nodejs function that is working fine locally. Now I need to run it on AWS Lambda, but looks like there are some handlers requirement which I am not understanding completely.

Below is my nodejs function that I need to run it on Lambda. Any idea what changes do I need to make to execute it on AWS? Thanks

```
(async function () {
DOMAIN = "abc.xyz.com";
KEY = "***";
const mailchimpClient = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional")(KEY);
    const run = async () => {
          const response = await mailchimpClient.senders.addDomain({
            domain: DOMAIN,
          });
          console.log(response);
        };
        
        run();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to export a function with a specific name: **handler**

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
  return "foo.bar"
}
```

In this handler, you just need to **return** something to mark as success or **throw an error** to mark as failure.

In your case, this should work:

```
var DOMAIN = "abc.xyz.com";
var KEY = "***";
const mailchimpClient = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional")(KEY);

exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  const response = await mailchimpClient.senders.addDomain({
    domain: DOMAIN,
  });
  console.log(response);
  return "success"
}
```

Here more examples and advanced configurations:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-samples.html
- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/blank-nodejs/function/index.js
- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/blob/main/sample-apps/nodejs-apig/function/index.js

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are using any framework to create your aws serverless code.

However, your usual code would be somthing like this.

```js
    exports.handler = function(event, context) {
      console.log('Lambda A Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
      context.succeed('Hello ' + event.name);
    };
```

If you want a easier way to work with AWS serverless code such as Lambdas  look at [arc.codes](https://arc.codes/docs/en/get-started/quickstart)

Also, here is a link to the AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I go with arc.codes or some alternative I would not need to make any changes on my actual function?

Comment: I am missing a lot of context of what you are doing, but in short even if you write your code. It will be a pain to keep updating it and handle deploys this gets more tiring when you are handling multiple lambda functions.

Arc codes makes this part easier and takes all that boilerplate code and complication and handles it for you.

Here is a video on it: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h38wYQ4uCrM